# Field cannot be resolved? Insert ) and ;?

Tags: android, eclipse

I made this code in Eclipse (for Android), but there are some errors .

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:id="@+id/click"
    />

<Edittext
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/meal"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/answerfield"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main:

```
package tip.com.tip;


import tip.com.R;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class com extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meal);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerfield);

        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick (View v) {
                String meal = edittext.getText().toString();
                String answer = "";

                if (meal.indexOf("$") == -1) {
                    meal = "$" + meal;
                }

                float fmp = 0.0F;
                NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                fmp = nf.parse(meal).floatValue();
                fmp *= 1.2;

                answer = " The meal's price is: " + nf.format(fmp);
                answerfield.setText(answer);
            }
         }
}
}
```

It write to me, that anserfield cannot be resolved, and Syntax error, insert ')' and in an another error insert ';'. What's the problem? I can't find the mistake.

Comment: And which lines are the errors at?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main);

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meal);
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerfield);

These are the R cannot be resolved problems.

answerfield.setText(answer); -> It has the answerfield cannot be resolved

and the second '}' in the end has the ) and ; problem.

Comment: See my answer below, should suffice to get rid of your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `setOnClickListener` is missing a `);`, e.g. a closing parenthesis and semicolon at the end.
- Your `answerfield` is never declared, thanks to [@WarrenFaith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180538/warrenfaith) for the hint.

I was also originally suggesting to try to remove the following line:

```
    import tip.com.R;
```

At least I recall once having problems with it. You might want to check for syntax errors in the layout XML file.

Comment: Additional: Variable `answerfield` is never declared/initialized. The TextView that is targeted is stored in the `textView` variable. And I have no idea why the import should be removed as it is used to get the layout and views...

Comment: I remember having problems like this once. Thanks for the hint though, updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problems except of );, but it's ok now. Thanks.

Comment: `android.R` is often imported instead of the custom `R` that each project uses. Its very very rare to me, that the custom R is making trouble. Anyway it's good when it helped to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing `);` from your call to `setOnClickListener`.